# How do you use functions like to_char or substring in a default column creation clause?

Tags: postgresql

We are converting a database from Oracle to PostgreSQL. We have run into the following error:

> ERROR:  operator is not unique: unknown - unknown
>
> HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.

when trying to create a table that has columns with default values that use functions. Here are two examples:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (
    id_first bigint,
    id_second bigint,
    id_third bigint,
    breaking_column varchar(122) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'TO_CHAR("ID_FIRST")||'-'||TO_CHAR(coalesce("ID_SECOND",0))||'-'||TO_CHAR(coalesce("ID_THIRD",0))'
);

CREATE TABLE another_example (
    code varchar(16),
    breaking_field varchar(18) DEFAULT 'substring("CODE" from 1 for 2)||'20'||substring("CODE" from 3 for 2)'
) ;
```

What would the PostgreSQL equivalent be to these Oracle DDL statements?

Comment: After all you will get `ERROR:  cannot use column references in default expression`. Try to play with functions/triggers.

Comment: Ah, yes, some explanation: using values of one column as a part of another column is not satisfying to the 2nd normal form.

Comment: You need a trigger for this in PostgreSQL. It can't evaluate `DEFAULT` expressions that reference other columns.

Comment: This is not related to the use of a function, but because you are trying to use another column

Comment: Thank you for your responses. These answer my question, but they are comments instead of answers so I can't accept any of them. Should I just close this question?